# read text file content and insert it into a mysql database

Tags: java, sql

Good day . I've the following code which i'm trying to make work . I have to read the content of a text file , which contains questions and save it to the database testsystem .

The main problem that i'm facing is that it's not inserted in the database. and i'm not sure whether it is reading the textfile or not.

any help will be glady appreciated

**JFrame and main**

```
public class StudentTestSystems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Lecturer panel = new Lecturer();

            panel.setVisible(true);
            panel.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            panel.setResizable(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Lecturer class**

```
public class Lecturer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    Font font = null;
    private JTextField fileField;
    private JButton uploadBtn;
    private JLabel message;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Lecturer() {
        super("LECTURE MENU");

        this.setSize(500, 270);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        fileField = new JTextField();
        fileField.setFont(font);
        fileField.setBounds(130, 110, 200, 25);

        Font font2 = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12);
        message = new JLabel("Type in the file name with it's extension. eg: File.txt");
        message.setFont(font2);
        message.setBounds(130, 140, 280, 25);
        message.setOpaque(true);

        uploadBtn = new JButton("UPLOAD");
        uploadBtn.setFont(font);
        uploadBtn.setBounds(340, 110, 95, 21);

        panel.add(fileField);
        panel.add(uploadBtn);
        panel.add(message);

        add(panel);

    /////// register event
        uploadBtn.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        String file = fileField.getText();

        SetGetQuestionFileName setGet = new SetGetQuestionFileName(file);

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;

        try {
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testsystem";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "cput");

            if (ev.getActionCommand().equals("UPLOAD")) {
                File filePathString = new File(file);

                fis = new FileInputStream(filePathString);

                if (fileField.getText().length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File field can't be empty. Try again", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    if (filePathString.exists() && filePathString.isFile()) {

                        try {
                            // the mysql insert statement
                            String query = " insert into users (category_questions, questions, quest_opt_a, , quest_opt_b, , quest_opt_c,  quest_opt_d, correct_option_answer )"
                                    + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                            // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                            preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                            preparedStmt.setString(1, "JDBC");
                            preparedStmt.setString(2, fileField.getText());
                            preparedStmt.setAsciiStream(3, fis, (int) filePathString.length());
                            //preparedStmt.setString   (3, "a");
                            preparedStmt.setString(4, "b");
                            preparedStmt.setString(5, "c");
                            preparedStmt.setString(6, "d");
                            preparedStmt.setString(7, "a");

                            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

                            // execute the preparedstatement
                            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                            //  myfile.closing();
                            conn.close();

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File successfuly uploaded", "INFORMATION", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            fileField.setText("");
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        } finally {
                            preparedStmt.close();
                            fis.close();
                            conn.close();
                        }
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File coudn't be found. Do check file name.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (ev.getActionCommand().equals("LOGOUT")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**SetQuestionFileName class**

```
public class SetGetQuestionFileName {

    String myfile;

    public SetGetQuestionFileName(String file) {
        setFileName(file);
    }

    public void setFileName(String file) {
        myfile = file;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return myfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to "format" your code a little bit and if possible break it down.. e.g you could remove the `import` statements. As it is right now, it is not readable

Comment: i've edited it don't know if it's better now in this way

Comment: where do you read the file? I see a `fis = new FileInputStream(filePathString);` but then you build the prepared Statement without touching `fis` again. Or am I missing something?

Comment: actually i was using this way to read the file but i removed it because it was not working. 
    FileReader filePath = new FileReader(details.getFileName()); // read characters at a time
          BufferedReader fileNames = new BufferedReader(filePath); //helps read file lines at a time
         
          while((line = fileNames.readLine()) != null)
          {
           
           arrayOutput.add(fileNames.readLine());
          }
         }

Comment: i don't know if i'm doing the correct thing. i have file which contains questions which are in the following way : "Category Questions " then question then the options and then a blank line and then the correct answer

Comment: basically, what i want is to read the file text content for now and insert it into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short version on how you can read a file (line by line):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

This is your query. There where too many `,` or empty column names and the number of columns and ? does not match:

```
String query = " insert into users (
                        category_questions, 
                        questions, 
                        quest_opt_a, 
                        ,              // empty column name
                        quest_opt_b, 
                        ,              // empty column name
                        quest_opt_c,  
                        quest_opt_d, 
                        correct_option_answer    
                )" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; // you have 7 columns (without the empty ones) but only 5 ?
```

Here a reformatted version of your query. I just removed the `,` and added 2 `?`

```
String query = "INSERT INTO users (
                        category_questions, 
                        questions, 
                        quest_opt_a,
                        quest_opt_b, 
                        quest_opt_c,  
                        quest_opt_d, 
                        correct_option_answer 
                 ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Now I am trying to understand the values you want to add:

```
preparedStmt.setString(1, "JDBC");    // so JDBC is your category ?
preparedStmt.setString(2, fileField.getText()); // I guess this should be the question?
preparedStmt.setString(3, "a");       // according to the column names this needs to be option A
preparedStmt.setString(4, "b");       // option b
preparedStmt.setString(5, "c");       // option c
preparedStmt.setString(6, "d");       // option d
preparedStmt.setString(7, "a");       // answer
```

So far so good. If I interpreted the column names correctly, this should work. The only thing left is now to get the real question text for column 2 (from the file).

I don't know how your file looks like, so I can just give you an example:

```
textfile in this format:  question? answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, correctAnswer
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What is the color of the sun? pink, blue, yellow, green, c
What is the smallest number? 3, 1, 7, 200, b
```

And this would be how you could read the file and fill the database all at once:

```
// prepare the query
String query = "INSERT INTO users (
                        category_questions, 
                        questions, 
                        quest_opt_a,
                        quest_opt_b, 
                        quest_opt_c,  
                        quest_opt_d, 
                        correct_option_answer 
                 ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

// load the file
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
// read the file line by line
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();

    String[] questionAnswer = line.split("?")[ // line.split["?"] will split the line into two strings, right at the ? and put those two strings into an array. 
    String question = questionAnswer[0]  // so [0] will access the first element in that array - the question 
    String[] answers = questionAnswer[1].split(","); // now we split the string after the ? into many strings divided by comma

    preparedStmt.setString(1, "JDBC");   
    preparedStmt.setString(2, question);  
    preparedStmt.setString(3, answers[0]);     
    preparedStmt.setString(4, answers[1]);      
    preparedStmt.setString(5, answers[2]);       
    preparedStmt.setString(6, answers[3]);      
    preparedStmt.setString(7, answers[4]);      

    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

There are many ways to read the line from your text file and split it into question and answer. It depends on the file you read from and how it is formatted.

FIY: you execute `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();` twice at the end :)

Comment: sorry, that's exactly how the file looks like   The format would be:
Category   (One of 4.  For example Combinational Logic)
Question   (One or more lines)
Four alternative answers (Labelled a., b., c., d.  One or more lines, each.)
Blank line
The correct option  (a., b., c. or d.  Only one option would be correct)
Two Blank lines

Comment: For example for the bellow question, i shall have in my Category_questions : Collections, and for my questions : Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection? and for my quest_opt_a : a. The cards you hold in a card game. etc and for correct_option_answer i shall have d insrted in the database table. this is the question  Collections
Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection?
a. The cards you hold in a card game.
b. Your favorite songs stored in your computer.
c. The players on a soccer team.
d. The number of pages in a book. 

d.

Comment: from what you explained above, i managed to get this, but now it's not only inserting and my upload button has become unresponsive, it doesn't trigger any event now. please i really need help

Comment: i don't know if you had a look at my last attempts